# Cisco LNS and per Customer VRF

Tags: cisco, isp, vrf

O.P.
Hi ,

I am trying to configure a Cisco LNS with VRF per Customer.
Each customer that dial (PPPoE) to the LNS will bond to the appropiate VRF.
The VRF will be assign according to the RADIUS AV-PAIR.
I have already configured the RADIUS and the Cisco Router but for some reason it did not work. ( the L2TP tunnel shuts immediately ).

### I will be thankful for any help or suggestion !!

My configuration:

( Cisco 3845 , IOS -advipservicesk9-mz.151-4.M8 )

Link : http://1drv.ms/1kuWjgM

Comment: Please show us what you've already configured.   What platform and IOS?

Comment: Hi User5025 , I have just edited my post with the info you've asked for.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the debug outputs for l2x, ppp, radius?

One thing I see is that you should set `ip unnumbered` on your Virtual-Template. `ip address negotiated` means your end will try to get an address from the client, when you should be offering one to them (via the Framed-IP-Address and Framed-IP-Netmask attributes in the RADIUS Access-Accept)

First create a loopback interface (or if you want you can use g0/0 but loopback is best practice) and give it a /32 address, then:

```
interface Virtual-Template1
 ip unnumbered Loopback0
```

Comment: Also you should put the Loopback interface you use for ip unnumbered on the vrf that the customer is attaching to. You can specify which loopback should be used for terminating PPP on a per-subscriber basis via the RADIUS AVpair: = "ip:ip-unnumbered=interface-name"